# Magento 2: PHP script exporting to csv will not export values for Backorders

Tags: magento2, php, export

I'm using Magento 2 as PIM for other shop solution. I need to export the backorders value once per hour until we have made an API.

The script below works fine, but values for 'backorders' are not exported. How can I fix that?

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

//Store id of exported products, This is useful when we have multiple stores. 
$store_id = 0;

$fp = fopen("export2.csv","w+");
$collection = $_objectManager- 
>create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')
->create()->addStoreFilter($store_id)
->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
->addAttributeToSelect(array('updated_at','sku','status','backorders','price'));

foreach ($collection as $product)
{
$data = array();
$data[] = $product->getUpdated_at();
$data[] = $product->getSku();
$data[] = $product->getStatus();
$data[] = $product->getBackorders(); (doesn´t export value)
$data[] = $product->getPrice();

fputcsv($fp, $data);    
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: So do you have these as product attributes ?

Comment: Both attributes should be system attributes. I found that "product_online" is instead "status". Do you know what to use for "backorders" with the dropdown values 1) "No Backorders, 2) Allow Qty Below 0, 3) Allow Qty Below 0 and notify customer)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<?php
require './app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$_objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$registry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);

//Store id of exported products, This is useful when we have multiple stores. 
$store_id = 0;

$fp = fopen("export2.csv","w+");
$collection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create()->addStoreFilter($store_id)->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')->addAttributeToSelect(array('updated_at','sku','product_online','backorders','price'));

foreach ($collection as $prod)
{
$product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prod->getId());
$data = array();
$data[] = $product->getUpdated_at();
$data[] = $product->getSku();
$data[] = $product->getStatus(); // For your product status

$stockRegistry = $_objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(),$product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
 // Use this if you need value as 0,1,2
$data[] = $stockitem->getBackorders();
// Use this if you need string value
$data[] = ($stockitem->getBackorders()) ? ($stockitem->getBackorders() == 1) ? "Allow Qty Below 0" : "Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer" : "No Backorders"; 
$data[] = $product->getPrice();
fputcsv($fp, $data);    
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Hello Abdul. Thank you for your suggestion. I found that the attribute "status" was what I looked for instead of "product_online" and the values are now exported in both your and my example. But the values for "backorders" are not. Seems that has to be extracted in an other way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419558/how-to-get-backorder-status-from-product-information-programmatically-in-magento.  Do you know how to get that info in my case.0: "No Backorders"
1: "Allow Qty Below 0 "
2: "Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer"

Comment: So you wanna know whats the Backorder setting set for the product from the above three options ?

Comment: @ThomasLester, please check the updated answer.